# How to show dialogue box while downloading in Internet Explorer as shown in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to create this type of dialogue window while downloading file in internet explorer.By default, IE shows, saves and opens option for downloading file but I want something as shown in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is changed from Firefox's settings to ask everytime before downloading.

UNLESS you mean that images show in a new tab and you want to download them instead, then if you have access to .htaccess file, add the following to the bottom:

```
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG 

<FilesMatch "\.(jpe?g)$">
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```